# How to remove subdomains except one page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, subdomain

Users navigate in web site with subdomains like

- xxx.abc.com/userpage/133,
- yyy.abc.com/userpage/133,
- zzz.abc.com/userpage/133,
- qqq.abc.com/userpage/133

As you can see there are several subdomains exits in our website.

I want to remove subdomains if user leaves from **/userpage/**

Such as, if navigates to :

- /ContactUs,
- /Register
- / (root)

How can I remove subdomains except just one action in MVC 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Convention Routing or Attribute Routing?

Comment: I use Convention Routing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to let IIS handle it. You can use the URL Rewrite module to redirect any request other than `/userpage/` where the domain is not the main one you want to use to the main domain.

If you insist on doing it through the MVC pipeline, your best bet is to use an action filter:

```
public class RedirectSubdomainFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.Url.Host != "maindomain.com" && !request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/userpage/"))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://maindomain.com" + request.Url.PathAndQuery);

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then, in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs` add:

```
filters.Add(new RedirectSubdomainFilter());
```

**EDIT (05/26/2016)**

I changed the action filter code above to use `StartsWith` instead of a direct comparison, as I neglected to notice that the URL may contain something after `/userpage/`.